# Get info (especial pk) of all column in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to get info of all column in a table
Example info about `type`, `name` column, especially info about `primary key` but it missing
I use

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename'
```

It's not contain info about `primary key`. How to get that thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND table_name = 'TableName'
```

Also maybe try

```
SELECT  i.name AS IndexName,
        OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
        COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName,
        c.*
FROM    sys.indexes AS i INNER JOIN 
        sys.index_columns AS ic ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
                                AND i.index_id = ic.index_id INNER JOIN
        sys.columns c   ON  ic.object_id = c.object_id
                        AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: it's only get primary column, has other one get all column include info `name`, `type`, `primary key` like `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename'` but it missing `primary key` ?

Comment: But it will gives only details about which column have primary key..I am right

Answer (score 0):

try with `sp_help [tablename]` it will give you primary key details

```
sp_help [tablename]
```

[sp_help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx)

[image]

Or if you need only details about primary key column  try with **Mr.Astander** answer

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND table_name = 'TableName'
```

Comment: but i need to use it in asp or php code and query `sp_help [tablename]` return `Array ( [Name] => tablename[Owner] => dbo [Type] => user table [Created_datetime] => xxxx )`

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve primary key information and join it to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and get primary key information with other columns. Please see the below query.

```
SELECT c.*,
       CASE WHEN keys.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 
       END AS is_primary  
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT col.COLUMN_NAME,col.TABLE_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tab
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
                ON Col.Constraint_Name = tab.Constraint_Name
                AND Col.Table_Name = tab.Table_Name
                WHERE Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY') keys 
ON c.COLUMN_NAME=keys.COLUMN_NAME AND c.TABLE_NAME=keys.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT TC.TABLE_NAME, CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME, C.DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    ON CU.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND CU.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND C.COLUMN_NAME = CU.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE TC.TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```